# Incorrect fragment name

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using fragments in my android application, when I run the program, the percentage name is displayed incorrectly, but after I switch to another fragment and perform some actions, everything becomes as it should be.
I set the title for the fragment on this line:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Soccer Quiz"
```

but it only applies when moving to another fragment.

My kotlin code:

```
 package com.example.soccerquiz

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import com.example.soccerquiz.databinding.FragmentWelcomeScreenBinding

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class WelcomeScreenFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding: FragmentWelcomeScreenBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_welcome_screen, container, false
            )

        binding.letsPlayButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
            Navigation.findNavController(view)
                .navigate(R.id.action_welcomeScreenFragment_to_quizFragment)
        }

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Soccer Quiz"

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzNLk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/66NXk.png

Please help me with my problem.

Comment: No one will be able to help you without some of your code

Comment: Is there a reason you are manually changing the title instead of actually setting the `android:label` in your navigation graph to the right string instead of `fragment_welcome_screen`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I learned how to use course navigation from the Internet, and the author of the course is not saying that you can use just a label. Thanks for the idea, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to change the title of fragment in  navigation graph.
No need to install manually, because when you start the program it does not always work, you have to switch between fragments.